# Page break with tablix in SSRS report leaves border behind, how to correct?

Tags: visual-studio, reporting-services

I selected "Omit border on page break", I tried "Keep together on one page if possible" and "Add a page break before" but the result is still the top border and some of the left and right border remaining on the first page and the tablix on the following page shows up normally except it has a missing top border.

**What can I do to get the border to stay next to its tablix?**

Answer (score 0):

If You have a Page Header You must to verify that exist a minimum space between last element inside it and bottom border of it.

|_____________________________________| <---  Last Element inside it

----------------------------------------- <-- Bottom border of Page Header